# Angular / Controller loading a json file fails with an exception I can not understand

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angularjs-http, angularjs-rootscope

sorry, maybe a stupid problem, but I am still a newbie with angular.

The code:

-- EDIT #2 -- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- -----

```
MyApp.controller('DataController', ['$http', function ($http) {

        var self = this;

        var objects = [];
        var loaded = false;

        var getObjects = function () {
            if(!loaded){
                setRawObjects();
            }
            return objects;
        };

        var setRawObjects = function(){
            $http.get('data/objects.json').success(function (response) {
                loaded=true;
            });
        }

        var openDetail = function () {
            console.log('test');
        }

        self.getObjects = getObjects;
        self.openDetail = openDetail;
    }]);
```

-- END OF EDIT #2 -- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- -----

The Error:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
    at angular.js:38
    at n.$digest (angular.js:17111)
    at n.$apply (angular.js:17337)
    at angular.js:1749
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4665)
    at c (angular.js:1747)
    at yc (angular.js:1767)
    at ee (angular.js:1652)
    at angular.js:30863
    at HTMLDocument.b (angular.js:3166)

angular.js:38Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
    at angular.js:38
    at n.$digest (angular.js:17111)
    at n.$apply (angular.js:17337)
    at angular.js:1749
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4665)
    at c (angular.js:1747)
    at yc (angular.js:1767)
    at ee (angular.js:1652)
    at angular.js:30863
    at HTMLDocument.b (angular.js:3166)
```

Exception is thrown twice. I connot imagine what it means, whats wrong?
This line seems to curse the problem:

```
return $http.get('data/objects.json').success(function(response) {
```

The controller is beeing initiated in this way:

```
EspanioApp.controller('DataController', ['$http', function ($http) {...
```

Do you have any hint for me how I can fix this?

cu n00n

Comment: Infinite $digest cycle...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the error:

> #### [$rootScope:infdig](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig) (Infinite `$digest` Loop)
>
> This error occurs when the application's model becomes unstable and each `$digest` cycle triggers a state change and subsequent `$digest` cycle. Angular detects this situation and prevents an infinite loop from causing the browser to become unresponsive.

Probably `setRawObjects` is bound in a not so proper way.

Also, I'm not really sure what you do with what `setRawObjects` is returning: I'd verify what it is returning - probably a [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q), which should be handled asynchronously, so a direct html binding wouldn't handle it properly.

For example, if you print the return on console, you'll find out that the `object` is `undefined`, while the `response` is not, which means that the return is executed before the success callback:

```
setRawObjects = function(){
    return $http.get('data/objects.json').success(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        objects = response.objects;
        loaded = true;
    });
}

var getObjects = function () {
    console.log(loaded);
    if(!loaded){
        setRawObjects();
    }
    console.log(objects);
    return objects;
};
```

So, instead of binding the function, bind the object directly:

```
MyApp.controller('DataController', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var self = this;
    self.objects = [];

    $http.get('data/objects.json').success(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        self.objects = response;
    });
}]);
```

Angular will watch it's been updated and will update the view as well.

Comment: .then instead of .success also not works. .... Maybe EDIT #1 is the problem. Would like to load my json file once on loading the page.

Comment: @n00n I have updated my answer. I think one of the main problem is that you want to return synchronously the response of an asynchronous request.

Comment: I aggree with you, ... but the return was a fail cause I used a bad code example. Without return, I get the same behaviour if it gets deleted

Comment: @n00n I have added a possible solution.